# ConcurrentModificationException thrown on Web Flow conversations during session replication

Tags: java, spring, jboss7.x, spring-webflow, session-replication

Our web application is running on a JBoss AS7 Cluster. We are also using Spring Web Flow (version 2.4.0.RELEASE) for the flow control. We are then facing a few problems during session replication. They are:

1. Because of session replication, objects stored on session will be serialized. However,the class `org.springframework.webflow.context.servlet.HttpServletRequestParameterMap` **is not serializable**. `NotSerializableException` may be thrown.
2. Spring Web Flow uses session to store conversations data on flow. This class `org.springframework.webflow.conversation.impl.ConversationContainer` will process the conversation data putting to/retrieving from session. We found that it uses `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.HashMap` to store conversations data on session. Thus, **`ConcurrentModificationException` may be thrown while both session replication and flow control handling are processing at the same time.**

Is anyone having the same or similar problems we face? And, is there any solution/alternative we can take to solve them?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to `synchronize` the part of code where you are updating this `hashmap` ?

Comment: this `HashMap` is updated by Spring Web Flow instead of our coding. Unless we change their code, it may not be possible to `synchronize` it